# Hide search params in Rails4 url (param not found: ---)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I wanted to hide params in rails url while searching.
so previously my link is like this,

```
http://localhost:3000/photos?utf8=%E2%9C%93&room_ids[]=534b6cc56d696e0f000d0000&commit=Refine+Search
```

i wanted to achieve like below link,

```
http://localhost:3000/photos
```

So i have changed the form_tag method to `Post` from `Get`.

```
<%= form_tag photos_path, :method => 'post' do %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

In route file mentioned as,

```
match '/photos/index', via: :post
```

After doing it giving error as,

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in PhotosController#create
param not found: photo
```

How to achieve it!!!

Comment: which version of rails you are using ?

Comment: I think the routing is trying to look for your create action in your controller. Have you tried to create a separate search action in your controller? Like in the following example, but using post instead of get: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#a-generic-search-form I have not tried it yet but I think it could work.

Comment: but i am trying to retrieve the result in index page, so thats why in route file i have mentioned as match '/photos/index', via: :post for form_tag get method

Comment: you can use named routes as per example in routes file


# Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)


  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

Comment: @jyrkim you are exactly write. Now i have created a separate action.

Answer (score 1):

If you want custom action to be performed on the params, better write a method in controller

```
#photos controller
def customize
  #custom action on params
end
```

add the method 'customize' in the routes and specify the route in the form.

Also, if your form doesn't have any fields from Photo model, you can use ActiveModel::Model for projecting an object.  Checkout http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/activemodel-model-rails-4-countdown-to-2013 and http://prasadsurase.github.io/blog/2014/02/19/using-activemodel-model-for-devise-based-invitations/ describing about how to use ActiveModel::Model.

Comment: Yes its better to write customized method. Thank you. @jyrkim given the reason for that error.

Answer (score -3):

```
<%= form_tag photos_index_path, :method => 'post' do %>
```

or

```
match '/photos/index', via: :post, as: :photos
```

In termial, type **rake routes**

```
match '/photos/index' => photos_index  /photos/index  photos#index

match '/photos/index', via: :post, as: :photos => photos  /photos/index  photos#index
```

According to [Rails Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide#routing)

Never use the legacy wild controller route. This route will make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests.

```
# very bad
match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

Don't use match to define any routes. It's removed from Rails 4.